# Sprite collision (spritecollideany() ) not working?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to coding and I am trying I have been unable to find out why my pygame spritecollideany() function is not doing anything. It is a platformer game and my player upon falling into the ground sprites does not do anything. I am *not* getting an error message and I think the syntax is correct but something in my code is not linking up. I'm sorry to post my all of my messy code but I don't know what the source of the problem is.

**The code that isn't doing anything:**

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, ground_sprites):
            print("COLLISION IS WORKING")
```

**All of the code**

```
import pygame, sys, random

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame Platformer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gravity = 0

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("marioLeft.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (self.x, self.y))

    def Move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 5

    def Draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def Collision(self):
        pass

class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (x, y))
        self.image.fill('White')

    def DrawGround():
        for entity in ground_sprites:
            screen.blit(entity.image, entity.rect)

#INSTANTIATION
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(100, 250)
player_group.add(player)

ground_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
ground1 = Ground(100, 500, 200, 100)
ground2 = Ground(450, 400, 200, 100)
ground_sprites.add(ground1, ground2)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill('Black')
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    gravity += 1
    if gravity >= 20:
        gravity = 20
    player.y += gravity

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, ground_sprites):
            print("COLLISION IS WORKING")

    Ground.DrawGround()
    player.Draw(screen)
    player.Move()
    player.Collision()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: There is no point in adding tags to the title of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) (and all other collision detection functions) uses the **`rect`** attributes of the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects to detect the collision. So you need to update the position stored in the `rect` attribute when you move the sprite:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def Move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 5
        self.rect.x = self.x               # <---
```

Actually, you don't need `self.x` and `self.y` at all. Use `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` instead:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("marioLeft.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = (x, y))

    def Move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 5

    def Draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```